# limiting variable with names to 127 chars, keeping whole names

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have this xml:

```
<Artists>
<Name>Name1</Name>
<Name>Name2</Name>
<Name>Name3</Name>
<Name>Name4</Name>
<Name>Name5</Name>
...
<Name>Namex</Name>
</Artists>
```

I don't know how long the list is.

And I want to end up with something like:

```
<Limit_Artists>Name1; Name2; Name3; Name4; Name5; Name(n)</Limit_Artists>
```

But where the total length of  must not exeed 127 chars and the last name must not "be split" in the middle. In other words I just need as many whole names from the top of the list, that fits within 127 chars.

I can put the names in a variable all together. but how can I stop before 127 chars?

best regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not efficient but

```
<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
   <xsl:value-of select="Name[string-length(string-join((preceding-sibling::Name, .), '')) le 127]" separator="; "/>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>
```

should do.

A complete example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer" select="127"/>

<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
   <xsl:value-of select="Name[string-length(string-join((preceding-sibling::Name, .), '')) le $limit]" separator="; "/>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the code counts only the contents of `Name` elements but outputs them concatenated by `;` so the output could that way be longer than 127. If you want to restrict the output to 127 characters then you have to change the `string-join` call to use

```
<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
   <xsl:value-of select="Name[string-length(string-join((preceding-sibling::Name, .), '; ')) le 127]" separator="; "/>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>
```

respectively the full example to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer" select="127"/>

<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
   <xsl:value-of select="Name[string-length(string-join((preceding-sibling::Name, .), '; ')) le $limit]" separator="; "/>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you could use sibling recursion along the following sibling axis, collecting the length of items until you hit the length you want to limit the output to. A complete example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer" select="127"/>

<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Artists/Name">
  <xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
  <xsl:variable name="new-length" select="$length + string-length()"/>
  <xsl:if test="$new-length le $limit">
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($length eq 0) then . else concat('; ', .)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Name[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$new-length"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above sample also only counts the `Name` characters but concatenates them so it would need to be adapted as well if you want to restrict the output to 127 characters. That could be done as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer" select="127"/>
<xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="'; '"/>

<xsl:template match="Artists">
  <Limit_Artists>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Limit_Artists>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Artists/Name">
  <xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
  <xsl:variable name="new-length" select="if ($length eq 0) then string-length() else $length + string-length($sep) + string-length()"/>
  <xsl:if test="$new-length le $limit">
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($length eq 0) then . else concat($sep, .)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Name[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$new-length"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <Artists>
      <Name>PreName1 lastname1</Name>
      <Name>PreName2 lastname2</Name>
      <Name>PreName3 lastname3</Name>
      <Name>PreName4 lastname4</Name>
      <Name>PreName5 lastname5</Name>
      <Name>PreName6 lastname6</Name>
      <Name>PreName7 lastname7</Name>
      <Name>PreName8 lastname8</Name>
    </Artists>

Comment: I see you use new-length to test if the next name exeeds 127, so I don't see were it goes wrong, but the output is:  

    <Limit_Artists>PreName1 lastname1; PreName2 lastname2; PreName3 lastname3; PreName4 lastname4; PreName5 lastname5; PreName6 lastname6; PreName7 lastname7</Limit_Artists>   Which is more than 130 chars. It seem like it takes the next name anyway?

Comment: Which characters do you want to count, only the ones that are content of the `Name` elements or also the output characters used for concatenation, that is the semicolon and spaces inserted in between `Name`s?

Comment: @user3740720, I have edited the answer and provided adapted samples that count the concatenation of `Name` characters and `; `.

Comment: Yes , of course - it was the seperator chars. Great Thanks again!